# MySQL create a function with mulitple inputs

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a MySQL function with multiple inputs, but keep getting an error:

```
DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION jb_test (a CHAR, b CHAR)
    -> RETURNS CHAR     
    -> DETERMINISTIC
    -> SET say = CONCAT(a,b);
    -> RETURN say;
    -> END$$
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FUNCTION jb_test (a CHAR, b CHAR)
RETURNS CHAR
DETERMINISTIC
SET say = CONCAT(a,b' at line 1
```

Comment: The error basically tells you the problem, you really need to be able to spot these kind of things on your own from such an error message

Comment: That was a typo Pekka, still getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION jb_test (a CHAR, b CHAR)
  RETURNS CHAR
   DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
     DECLARE say CHAR;
     SET say = CONCAT(a,b);
     RETURN say;
    END|
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the function is as follows:

```
 mysql> CREATE FUNCTION function_name (s CHAR(20))
 mysql> RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
  -> RETURN CONCAT('Hello, ',s,'!');
```

The argument is as given below

```
FUNCTION function_name (s CHAR(20))

FUNCTION sp_name ([func_parameter[,...]])
```

Refer [Mysql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html)